# Binary logging framework in C++

Tags: logging, embedded, protocols

There are a lot of logging frameworks for many languages out there. But I did not find any framework suitable for certain embedded applications. I want to log data in an embedded device and neither have a lot of bandwith or a lot of memory available.

The logging framwork I want should be usable like usual logging frameworks with descriptive strings etc. directly inside the source code. I would like to extract the descriptive strings from the source code to a seperate file (e.g. xml) and replace them in the binary output with ids. In an analysis tool, i would then take these IDs and display the text again. For PC debugging I could directly use the string.

I want to know about feasible methods to provide message id's, formatting instructions and accompanied parameter values, but put to the communication port in kind of a compact binary format.

Also I'd like to avoid seeing the footprint blowup with c++, introduced by

```
#include <iostream>
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

et. al like with the standard c libraries type formatting libraries.

Comment: Finally we've implemented our own solutions for very small systems. One of the points is about formatting support implementation: If you don't have and use a FPU, formatting stuff for `float`, `double` types isn't necessary. But you can still stick to the standard `newlib` interfaces, to override certain stuff.

Comment: _'@πάνταῥεῖ: ????'_ Citinng from the site's policies: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: okay, i am out here. Did not want to offend anyone. I better delete this question then. For you info, i log binary events and have a seperate table to analyse them. String messages only during development.

Comment: You can use compact wire formats and decode outside of your system. [Google protobuf and nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/) is useful for implementing such. No offense from your site, just off topic.

Comment: @_yggdrasil_ Next question from comments will be _'What did yo try, and where did it fail'_ :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thanks i will have a look into nanopb.

Comment: _@Yggdrasil_ I could imagine a mechanism that declares `.proto` files for some standard logging situations and instrument these via [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options), e.g. providing a generic rendering format mechanism for the actually available data members in the message.

Comment: Can you clarify, do you mean to save logs internally for later retrieval? Or do you just mean live logging? If the latter, just log to a USB port or a RS232 port etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Seriously? Transport layer matters here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to easily extract strings from source code and replace them with unique ids for binary output?

Well I think you want to log your devices something like a `error message id` and pass some certainly known parameter values along, to be formatted as well human readable text at the client's side.

E.g. using [`google protobuf`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) along with [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) for such protocol should be appropriate:

```
message DebugLogMessage {
   extensions 4 to max;
}

message SystemStateLogMessage {
    option render_format = "System temp: %d, Restarts: %d";
    extend DebugLogMessage {
        optional SystemStateLogMessage bar = 126;
    }
    optional int64 temp;
    optional int16 restarts;
}
```

The `render_format` option is meant to be used at the client site solely. On the small target you'll only need to  provide the current values.

To provide the data parameters from a small embedded system, [Nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/) establishes a good binding for c language, while preserving a reasonably small footprint.

**NOTE**
That's just a rough idea sketching out what I think you'll need. I hope you can catch the abstraction. I'm not saying that this is the only viable way, to realize what I understood you want to have, neither I'm going to give you production ready code.

Comment: nanopb looks good, didn't now the render_format option from protobufs so far. Guess I could do what i want to achieve with a multi-step build process. Extract the strings by some grep + code generation to create the protobuf stuff, which is then used to generate functions for logging or so.

Comment: @Yggdrasil _'didn't now the render_format option from protobufs so far'_ Note that the `render_format` option was meant as a sample for a [custom option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) actually. But since you accepted before I had stated this, I think you figured out this yourself meanwhile.

Comment: You can do better if you introduce a compile time tool which collects the format strings, filenames and source line numbers. The calls to Log() output hash of the filename (a 16 bits constant), line number and the variadic arguments. Alternatively instead of the filename hash and source line the Log() can output address of the place where it is called from. Example https://github.com/larytet/emcpp/blob/master/src/Log.h#L184